# What are options to prototype 'feedback' from the user after response in chatbot

Tags: c#, botframework

I am just thinking could I see what would be the options to prototype 'feedback' from the user after each response in my chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework using `C#`.

It is just like a "thumbs up/down" buttons after each response. I am not sure whether i can do it in c# using Microsoft Bot Framework but if the bot always accepted UP/DOWN as a potential feedback, I could store it somewhere next to the response.

Can someone have any idea?

[image: sanpshot]

Comment: Anything preventing you of sending the response in card with 2 buttons?

Comment: what is this card with 2 button ? i am very new to this , any reference can you send please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to present a Up/Down or Like/Dislike button to get feedback from the user could be using [RichCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards) (the link points to a C# sample).

In particular a [HeroCard](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/reference/#herocard) might be suitable for this, where you can present the response as the card content and then two buttons to get the feedback.

In the [Channel inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Skype?f=HeroCard&e=example1) you will be able to check how a hero card is being rendered in those channels that support it.

Comment: I tried but how do I handle the button event, I used Action Type as PostBack for button but it will post that message to conversation. also image on button doesn't render in emulator.

Comment: postBack won't post the message back to the conversation; imBack it will (https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html#cardaction). Though, not all the channels support postBack. Handle the response is exactly the same as with any other message; you need to "wait". There is no "click" button event. After sending the card, do context.Wait(MyMethodToHandleFeedback) and implement that method. Once the user clicks, you will received the response there

Comment: Yes @Ezequiel, I did the same way only calling the contrext.wait(feddbackresponse). but after clicking on button it display the value "Like" in botemulator which i set on value property of the button. attached a snapshot in my question.

Comment: It's fine, unless postback is supported in the emulator (which I don't recall at this moment) that's the expected behavior. A button is a "shortcut" for sending a message. If the user type Like it will behave the same

Comment: Thanks! @Ezequiel

Comment: Hey @Ezequiel Is it possible to save this feedback along with the correspondence response ?. since I am using document db NOSQL so , when user clicks, it goes to a complete new message not with the respective response.