# Capture user behavior in chat bot using microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, user-feedback

I want to capture the user behavior in my chatbot after each response given by bot. it basically a feedback, like/dislike button in Facebook.

Is it possible in MS bot framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what are options to prototype 'feedback' from the user after response in chatbot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065052/what-are-options-to-prototype-feedback-from-the-user-after-response-in-chatbot)

Comment: yes, but any body has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `feedback yes no` button or `like` button using rich card or hero card.

Many messaging channels provide the ability to attach richer objects. The Bot Framework has the ability to render rich cards as attachments. There are several types of cards supported: Hero Card, Thumbnail Card, Receipt Card, Sign-In Card, Animation Card, Video Card and Audio Card. Once the desired Card type is selected, it is mapped into an Attachment data structure. Check out the key code located in the CardsDialog class where the message.Attachments property of the message activity is populated with a card attachment.

```
public async Task DisplaySelectedCard(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    var selectedCard = await result;

    var message = context.MakeMessage();

    var attachment = GetSelectedCard(selectedCard);
    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    await context.PostAsync(message);

    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

Hero Card

The Hero card is a multipurpose card; it primarily hosts a single large image, a button, and a "tap action", along with text content to display on the card. Check out the GetHeroCard method in the CardsDialog class for a Hero Card sample.

```
private static Attachment GetHeroCard()
{
    var heroCard = new HeroCard
    {
        Title = "BotFramework Hero Card",
        Subtitle = "Your bots — wherever your users are talking",
        Text = "Build and connect intelligent bots to interact with your users naturally wherever they are, from text/sms to Skype, Slack, Office 365 mail and other popular services.",
        Images = new List<CardImage> { new CardImage("https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg") },
        Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Get Started", value: "https://learn.microsoft.com/bot-framework") }
    };

    return heroCard.ToAttachment();
}
```

i have create a sample. Sharing image with you. On click of Yes it will show a card to give rating as well.

[image]